# React JS: Explanation of this.props.items.map feature

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, reactive-programming

I am using React JS for Rendering the HTML content. The issue is I am not able to understand particular section of code what it does.

If you can see a basic sample of a Todo List from the below link
**http://facebook.github.io/react/**

```
<script type='text/jsx'>
        /** @jsx React.DOM */ 

        var TodoList = React.createClass({
                render: function(){ 
                        var createItem = function(itemText) {
                          return <li>{itemText}</li>;
                        };
                        return <ul>{this.props.items.map(createItem)}</ul>;
                    }
            });

        var TodoApp = React.createClass({
                getInitialState: function(){
                    return {items:[], text: ''}
                },
                onChange: function(e)
                {
                    this.setState({text: e.target.value});
                },
                handleSubmit: function(e)
                {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var nextItems = this.state.items.concat([this.state.text]);
                    var nextText = ''
                    this.setState({items: nextItems, text: nextText});
                },
                render:function(){
                    return (
                        <div>
                            <h3>ToDo List</h3>
                            <TodoList items={this.state.items}/>
                            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                                <input type="text" onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.text}/>
                                <button>Add #{this.state.items.length+1}</button>
                            </form> 
                        </div>
                    )
                }
            });

        React.render(<TodoApp />, document.getElementById('toDoListApp'));
    </script>
```

I am basically not able to understand what **map** does and how create item parameters are working. Could anyone provide details on the same:

```
var TodoList = React.createClass({
                    render: function(){ 
                            var createItem = function(itemText) {
                              return <li>{itemText}</li>;
                            };
                            return <ul>{this.props.items.map(createItem)}</ul>;
                        }
                });
```

Thanks,
Ankit

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`map` is not a feature of React.js. You can call this function on any array you want. You should look at its [documentation at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for that.

Basically, map is for converting an array to another array with modified items.
For example:

```
[1,2,3].map(function(item){
    return item+1;
})
```

would return a new array like this: `[2,3,4]`

In your example, map is used to convert an array with items of type "string" to an array of React.DOM.li elements.

The autor of your example could also have done it like this

```
var TodoList = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return <ul>{this.createItems(this.props.items)}</ul>;
    },
    createItems: function(items){
        var output = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) output.push(<li>{items[i]}</li>);
        return output;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

`props` is an object containing properties passed from a parent to a child component.

So `props.items` is the property named `items` which is an array.

`props.item.map()` maps the `items` arrary to an array of `li`s.

Comment: Thanks, I liked this map function very much. I saw your answer and looked at its javascript Documentation.

Answer (score 3):

It will take `this.props.items` array, pass each item to the `createItem` function, and then return an array of the returned values of each call.

Specifically for that code, if you had this in `this.props.items`:

```
["Item 1 text", "Item 2 text", ..]
```

You'd get something like this from the map call:

```
["<li>Item 1 text</li>","<li>Item 2 text</li>",..]
```

Answer (score 3):

`this.props.items` is an array and `map` return the new array according to `callback function` that provide as an first argument, it is quit easy to using ES6 and JSX.

`<tr> { this.arr.map((obj, i) => <td key={i}> {obj.name} </td>) } </tr>`

In our example it will return array of `td's`

Comment: could you plese explain this code to me? what's obj? how would this work if the key was a uuid?

Comment: `map` takes a callback function as a first argument and the `callback function` called for each element of `array`, callback function give you element on first `parameter` in our example is `obj`.

you can use `obj.uuid`